# I am trying to add Rahul Mohindra Oscilator to R

Tags: r, financial

I am beginner in R and recently trying to create a algorithm for trading (quite challenging) and do a backtest. The thing is TTR and Quantmod do not have the function I need so I tried and create it. So I found the function in a website but is no in R language but one called Pine.

The formula is called RMO (Rahul Mohindra Oscillator): This is the formula in Pine language that I found:

```
    Raul Mohindra Oscillator

    study(title = "Rahul Mohinder Oscillator", shorttitle="RMO_LB")
    C=close
    cm2(x) => sma(x,2) #sma simple moving average#
    ma1=cm2(C)
    ma2=cm2(ma1)
    ma3=cm2(ma2)
    ma4=cm2(ma3)
    ma5=cm2(ma4)
    ma6=cm2(ma5)
    ma7=cm2(ma6)
    ma8=cm2(ma7)
    ma9=cm2(ma8)
    ma10=cm2(ma9)
    SwingTrd1 = 100 * (close - ( ma1+ma2+ma3+ma4+ma5+ma6+ma7+
         ma8+ma9+ma10)/10)/(highest(C,10)-lowest(C,10))
    SwingTrd2=ema(SwingTrd1,30) #ema exponential moving average#
    SwingTrd3=ema(SwingTrd2,30)
    RMO= ema(SwingTrd1,81)


   Buy=cross(SwingTrd2,SwingTrd3)
   Sell=cross(SwingTrd3,SwingTrd2)


   Bull_Trend=ema(SwingTrd1,81)>0
   Bear_Trend=ema(SwingTrd1,81)<0
   Ribbon_kol=Bull_Trend ? green : (Bear_Trend ? red : blue)
   Impulse_UP= SwingTrd2 > 0
   Impulse_Down= RMO < 0
   bar_kol=Impulse_UP ? green : (Impulse_Down ? red : (Bull_Trend ?    green : blue))
   bgcolor(Ribbon_kol)
   plot(RMO,color=bar_kol, style=histogram)
   hline(0)
```

I am struggling in the last part where the function should plot a histogram of the calculation indicating in green Bull Trend and in Red Bear Trend. I don't manage to translate it to R language.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
    RMO <- function(x) {
    ma1 <- SMA(x,2)
    ma2 <- SMA(ma1,2)
    ma3 <- SMA(ma2,2)
    ma4 <- SMA(ma3,2)
    ma5 <- SMA(ma4,2)
    ma6 <- SMA(ma5,2)
    ma7 <- SMA(ma6,2)
    ma8 <- SMA(ma7,2)
    ma9 <- SMA(ma8,2)
    ma10 <- SMA(ma9,2)

    SwingTrd1 <- 100 * (x - (ma1+ma2+ma3+ma4+ma5+ma6+ma7+ma8+ma9+ma10)/10)/(max(x,10)-min(x,10))
    SwingTrd2 <- EMA(SwingTrd1,30)
    SwingTrd3 <- EMA(SwingTrd2,30)

    RMO <- EMA(SwingTrd1,81)

    Bull_Trend <- RMO < 0
    Bear_Trend <- RMO > 0
```

Thanks for your time!!!

Kylian Pattje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, RMO formular  in R

```
      RMO <- function(x) {
    ma1 <- SMA(x,2)
    ma2 <- SMA(ma1,2)
    ma3 <- SMA(ma2,2)
    ma4 <- SMA(ma3,2)
    ma5 <- SMA(ma4,2)
    ma6 <- SMA(ma5,2)
    ma7 <- SMA(ma6,2)
    ma8 <- SMA(ma7,2)
    ma9 <- SMA(ma8,2)
    ma10 <- SMA(ma9,2)

    SwingTrd1 <- 100 * (x - (ma1+ma2+ma3+ma4+ma5+ma6+ma7+ma8+ma9+ma10)/10)/(max(x,10)-min(x,10))

    STC <- SwingTrd1 + 20

    SwingTrd2 <- (EMA(STC,30))
    SwingTrd3 <- EMA(SwingTrd2,30)

    RMO <- EMA(SwingTrd1,81)

    plot(RMO, type = "h")
    abline(SwingTrd2, col = "blue")
    abline(SwingTrd3, col = "red")
  }
```

Hope is helpful as it was for me!!

Comment: need library(quant mod) and library(TTR).